# Website Body Won't Extend All the Way Up

Tags: css, web

My website, www.clinkstr.tk, has the body/middle section. It won't extend all the way up. For some reason, it's different on every monitor. Can you help me fix my code to fix and optimize it? I want to make it look like the registration/main page of Facebook or Twitter.

CSS Code:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#pageTop {
background-color:rgba(40,138,255,0.8);
color: #ffffff;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: block;
border-bottom:rgba(0,100,255,0.8);
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap {
width: 1200px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo > a {
background:url(../images/logo.png);
float: left;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest {
float: left;
height: 50px;
width: 230px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #home > a {
display: block;
float: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px 9px;
margin-top: 4px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-right: 9px;
padding-left: 9px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #home > a:hover {
color:#FFBB4B;
background:url(../images/roundedrectangle60x42.png) no-repeat;
}
#pageMiddle{
margin: 0px auto;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
}
#pageMiddle > #loginsignup{
height:640px;
width:860px;
margin: auto auto;
}
#pageMiddle > #loginsignup > #greetings{
float: left;
width: 350px;
height: 610px;
background:url(../images/greetingbackground.png) no-repeat;
}
#pageMiddle > #loginsignup > #signinbox{
float:right;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 110px;
width: 500px;
background:url(../images/signinbox.png) no-repeat;
}
#pageMiddle > #loginsignup > #signupbox{
margin: 0px auto;
float:right;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background:url(../images/signupbox.png) no-repeat;
}
#pageBottom{
display: block;
padding: 24px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
```

}

Comment: Different on every monitor or on every browser?  Both are common issues to run into although you will typically see variations in color across monitors and variations in alignment depending on browser and screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the ad space displayed at the top of the page pushes the content down which makes it appear not to "extend all the way up" because the ad space is blank. The reason it appears differently across different browsers or "monitors" is because AdBlock removes the frame altogether. If my memory serves me correctly using a .tk domain forceably imposes these ads so you may need to switch to a regular domain in order to remove this space at the top of the page for browsers without AdBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a mess. In any case, the problem is that you have a bunch of inline styling inside your `<ins>` tags defining `height: 90px` which push the content down.

Comment: I don't have a <ins> tag anywhere nor a height: 90px. I would appreciate it if you get me more specific directions and information.

Comment: You have an `<ins>` tag with those attributes just below your `adsbygoogle.js`. Furthermore, that script probably messes up the HTML as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh! I just remembered that I had the Google ads script and that I have Adblock. It all makes sense now. The other devices I had didn't have Adblock so it showed the white bar.